# Addition array values in php

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

This is my array. This data coming from `MySQL` Database. How to do sum values using `PHP`. Many people's name in this array.

```
    Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => Zoni
            [MARK] => 41
        )

    [2] => Array
        ( 
            [NAME] => Zoni
            [MARK] => 12
        )

    [3] => Array
        (   
            [NAME] => Nari
            [MARK] => 37
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Nari
            [MARK] => 51
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Lesi
            [MARK] => 64
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Lesi
            [MARK] => 28
        )
)
```

I have tried this code:

```
$sum = 0; 
foreach ($rv as $item) { 
    $sum += $item[MARK]; 
}
```

I want result like this. How to write `PHP` code for this result. I want display like below result using `php`.

```
Zoni = 53
Nari = 88
Lesi = 92
```

Comment: Show us the code you have been trying so far + tell us what the issue is with that code

Comment: All you have to do is to give it a try.

Comment: `$sum = 0;
foreach ($rv as $item) {
 $sum += $item[MARK]; }` This is I tried code.

Comment: why is the first two array keys title and in the subsequent arrays its title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your array in the question, I called it `$ar`.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($ar); $i++) {
    $uni = array_unique($ar[$i]);
    foreach ($uni as &$v) {
        $add[$v][] = $uni["MARK"];
        unset($uni["MARK"]);
        $sum[$v] = array_sum($add[$v]);
    }
}

print_r($sum);
```

Will output like this:

```
Array ( 
    [Zoni] => 53 
    [Nari] => 88 
    [Lesi] => 92 
)
```

`array_unique()` to exclude dublicates. `array_sum()` to count the `MARK` values in the array with identical `NAME` value as reference. `unset()` to delete the `MARK` values so that only the names and the summary of marks remain. Result will be assigned to the array `$sum`.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/D1KYt)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: `[TITLE] => Lesi [Subject] => maths
            [MARK] => 28` if I have like this array. can I use this your code my friend.

Comment: Thank you and you're welcome. I answered to your code in the question. If you want additional changes in the array, you should have put this in your question before or just open a new question for this matter